# Python populating x and y values incrementally

Tags: python, list, random

I'm attempting to come up with a for loop to populate a dictionary of lists(don't know if that's the proper way to say that) evenly. I.E. I start with

```
world = [(0,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,0,0)...]
```

repeats as long as needed
And I want to assign the first two values in a fashion like

```
0,0

0,1

1,0

0,2

2,0

1,2

2,1

2,2

3,0

0,3

1,3

3,1

2,3

3,2

3,3

And so on
```

Basically I want every x and y value possibly up to a certain value to be used. I've tried several things all day with absolutely no success

As for the third value I just have a noise function that defines it based on the x and y of that list

Comment: Not sure I understand how the example input leads to the output.  Do you basically want every size-2 combination of indexes into your `world` list of tuples? I don't also don't understand where the dictionary comes in.  What do you mean by "third value"?  In your example output, each element only has two values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [(x, y, 0) for x, y in product(range(5), repeat=2)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 3, 0), (0, 4, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0), (1, 3, 0), (1, 4, 0), (2, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0), (2, 3, 0), (2, 4, 0), (3, 0, 0), (3, 1, 0), (3, 2, 0), (3, 3, 0), (3, 4, 0), (4, 0, 0), (4, 1, 0), (4, 2, 0), (4, 3, 0), (4, 4, 0)]
```

this?

To apply the noise function, `[(x,y,func(x,y)) for x` etc.

BTW, this is "a list of tuples", not "a dictionary of lists".

Comment: Let me test this out. I figured out the list of tuples after I typed this out.

Comment: @THUNDERGROOVE: all credit goes to [Raymond Hettinger](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger) who wrote the itertools module.